# Variables for fields in MS Word

Tags: ms-word, automation

We have a template in Word, where we find and replace variables. e.g:Client Name.

Is there a way to autofill the variables with the content entered. I explored through mail merge and template/form fields. But did not get a user friendly material for a novice.

Kindly let me know if there is an walkthrough for the same.

Comment: Walk-through http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/word-mail-merge-a-walk-through-the-process-HA001034920.aspx

Answer (score 6):

I think you can do it with some fields. I recently had to overcome some of the limitations of Word's mail merge features by creating local variables.

You can create local variables in word by doing the following

`{ SET localClientName { MERGEFIELD ClientName }}`

The above creates a local variable called localClientName which can be referenced anywhere in the document by the following:

`{ localClientName }`

You just need to be sure to use the matched quotes. These are created by pressing 'ctr + F9.' It will not work if you use normal curly braces.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can set variables like this:

```
{ SET someTextToRepeat "Here's some plain text" }
{ SET paymentDetails "Payment Details: { MERGEFIELD Invoice.Total }" }
```

And you can reference paymentDetails like this

```
{ paymentDetails }
```

Remember not to just type the {} but press Ctrl-F9 to create them.